# Image on webpage stopped loading after SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I recently changed my website (shared hosting) from HTTP to HTTPS. I am  able to load the webpage but the images are throwing 403 error.
This is my test page: at https://www.manogat.com/ssltest.html

```
=====================
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="mr-IN">
  <head>
    <title>ssl image loading test</title>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <img style="float:left;" src="img/mano_logo.png" alt="" id="logo-image" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
=====================
```

browser throws error 403 for the logo.png. with this url in the console.log https://www.manogat.com/img/mano_logo.png

If I copy and paste the url in separate window or tab, the image loads just fine.

What is wrong after shifting to ssl/https ?
Please help

Comment: Do you have any kind of access control based on the HTTP referrer implemented perhaps? And forgot to change from an HTTP to an HTTPS URL in there?

Comment: I do not think of any such access control. Where should I look for one?

Comment: Don't know, where do you configure the rest of this stuff? Hosting panel?

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly some form of access control based on the Referer header. This can be easily checked. With a `https://...` referrer it gives a 403 Forbidden:

```
$ curl -v -H "Referer: https://www.manogat.com/ssltest.html"  https://www.manogat.com/img/mano_logo.png
...
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

With no Referer header instead it gives 200:

```
$ curl -v https://www.manogat.com/img/mano_logo.png
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

With a `http://` instead of a `https://` referrer it works too:

```
$ curl -v -H "Referer: http://www.manogat.com/ssltest.html"  https://www.manogat.com/img/mano_logo.png
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Note that the check seems to explicitly look either for an empty header or for `http://www.manogat.com`. One gets a 403 if the Referer header is set to a different HTTP site, like `http://example.com`.

It is unclear where this check comes from, since nothing is known about the host, server and configuration.

Comment: hmm. I can see what you have demoed above. However in your second paragraph you say ....With a http:// instead of a https:// referrer it works too: ........but in the example you still used https.......(and it threw 403).........I think, the example needs to be corrected..........On my side, where would such referrer control be ?

Comment: @user1940163: sorry, cut and paste error. *".On my side, where would such referrer control be"* - server configuration, web application, maybe even some WAF in front of it ... - hard to tell since there is absolutely nothing known about your setup.

Comment: Yes. I got it. I myself had hacked the .htaccess file 17years back and this was one of the starting lines............I added a line 

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^https://www..............com" allowed=1

to allow https in the referrers and it worked for me ...........thanks for the guidance.